# HiveQL - How to find the column value is numeric or not using any UDF?

Tags: sql, hive, hiveql, numeric

Basically i would like to `return rows` based on one `column value`.

If the column contains `non numeric` values, then return those rows from a hive table.

Any `UDF` is available in `Hive`?

Answer (score 22, accepted):

I believe Hive supports `rlike` (regular expressions).  So, you can do:

```
where col rlike '[^0-9]'
```

This looks for any non-digit character.  You can expand this, if your numeric values might have decimal points or commas.

Comment: an extra like  for 'rlike'

Comment: The above answer is wrong ,if white space is there in between.  Try the below , u can see wrong results          select 
if(substring(trim("10 10"),1,4) rlike '[^0-9]',"NUMERIC","STRING") as result
from <Any Table Name>
limit 1;

Comment: @vinu.m.19 . . . Spaces are non-numeric in all databases I'm familiar with.  Of course, if you want to know if there are digits *and* spaces, then the regular expression would need to be adapted.

Answer (score 15):

Use `cast(expr as <type>)`. A `null` is returned if the conversion does not succeed.

```
case when cast(col as double) is null then 'N' else 'Y' end as isNumber
```

or simply use Boolean expression in the WHERE: `cast(col as double) is not null`

Also you can create isNumber macro:

```
create temporary macro isNumber(s string)
       cast(s as double) is not null;
```

And use it in your queries:

```
hive> select isNumber('100.100'), isNumber('100'), isNumber('.0'), isNumber('abc');
OK
_c0     _c1     _c2     _c3
true    true    true    false
```

If you need to check for Integer then use `cast(s as Int)`

This approach works correctly with negative and fractional numbers.