# Data Validation at the time of import in hive

Tags: hive

Is there any way to validate data at the time of import in hive , as hive is schema on read , any help would be appreciated.
Thanks

Comment: This is vague to answer. However see below link for some validation technique in Hive. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56259500/perform-validation-and-checks-on-hive-table-may-not-be-a-duplicate

Comment: Thanks @Vikrant Rana